# Reactive form in Angular, with Material Library. When added validation, displayed message bit shifted from exact form-field border

Tags: css, angular, forms, angular-material

```
html : <div style="margin-left:20px;">
  <h3>Add New Shop</h3>
  <div class="example-container">
    <form
      [formGroup]="addShopFormGroup"
      (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
      class="example-form"
    >
   <p>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width">
      <mat-label>Shop Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput [ngModel]="shopName" formControlName="shopName" />
      <mat-hint *ngIf="checkError('shopName', 'required')"
        >Shop Name is required</mat-hint
      >
      <mat-error *ngIf="checkError('shopName', 'minlength')"
        >Shop Name should be more than 5 characters</mat-error
      >
      <mat-error *ngIf="checkError('shopName', 'maxlength')"
        >Shop Name should be less than 20 characters</mat-error
      >
    </mat-form-field>
  </p>
  <p>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="example-full-width">
      <mat-label>Shop Address</mat-label>
      <textarea matInput formControlName="shopAddress"></textarea>
      <mat-error *ngIf="checkError('shopAddress', 'required')"
        >Shop Address is required</mat-error
      >
      <mat-error *ngIf="checkError('shopAddress', 'maxlength')"
        >Shop Address should be less than 200 characters</mat-error
      >
    </mat-form-field>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img mat-card-sm-image />
  </p>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!addShopFormGroup.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
css : p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
```

[This is the output that I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwFbQ.png)

[This is the output that is desired, wherein the required message must start exactly below the border of the form-field.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf71S.png)

- Provided, I am not supposed to change the appearance of material form to anything else other than "outline".

Comment: Please do not add a link to your code. See [mcve] and [edit] the question to contain all relevant code within the question itself. Links can rot, people might not be able to access the website, there might be licensing issues etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
}
```

See the [forked snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-form-group-validation-cg8nc3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css).

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it's working perfectly. But is there any possible way to shift the message without important, as important is not supposed to be used.

Comment: It's possible. I edited my answer. Add `:host` and then you don't have to use `!important`.